# Encrypting emails with own pgp key in Thunderbird

Tags: encryption, thunderbird, email, pgp

*Don't know if this is the right SE to ask this question, feel free to move the question to another one*.

Many emails in my inbox are not encrypted: the sender has is not technically educated enough, or we did not exchange pgp keys.

A problem is that if the mailbox is hacked, the messages can be read by a hacker. I was wondering if it is possible to encrypt such messages with my own pgp key (and do this in an automatic manner in Thunderbird). In that case even if a hacker succeeds in opening the inbox, he/she cannot make sense of the messages stored there.

In that case the hacker will need to find a way to fetch the private pgp key of the owner of the inbox, which makes it a step harder. Evidently the messages were once plain text, but one can hope that by the time the hacker opens the mailbox, at least all read messages are encrypted. Furthermore it can protect one against tampering with messages (adding/modifying content).

question: *How to automatically encrypt unencrypted emails in Thunderbird using pgp?*

*edit*: email system is IMAP.

Comment: I don't know, but you should clarify whether you have a POP3 or (probably) IMAP inbox. And why don't you just delete your messages from the server after you downloaded them?

Comment: @ByteCommander: because you can install Thunderbird on multiple devices (each with a shared private pgp key).